# Query results mismatch

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I created a temporary table T3_final as following. I wanted to count the distinct no. of tracking ids in that on destination_address_id level . However the numbers are overstated(73 for the particular destination address id ) . Why is this happening?

Edit:Updated the question details. The image provided has 16 tracking ids for that particular destination address id but the final results is showing 70+ tracking ids for the same. Added the sql code containing T3 and route temp tables and also included code till the final output.

Sample dataset for T3 table(ordered by tracking_id)

```
|   lat1    |   long1    | actual_lat | actual_long |   tracking_id   | destination_address_id | distance |
|-----------|------------|------------|-------------|-----------------|------------------------|----------|
| 41.867318 | -87.625199 |  41.866985 |  -87.625177 | TBA291146931000 | 57137334115            |    37.11 |
| 41.699121 | -87.685905 |  41.699075 |  -87.685903 | TBA294192909000 | 52320567               |     5.08 |
| 41.839378 |  -87.64605 |  41.839463 |  -87.646085 | TBA294636573000 | 60406350705            |     9.95 |
| 41.893888 | -87.960975 |  41.893863 |  -87.960985 | TBA295159303000 | 85918178503            |     2.87 |
| 41.801833 | -87.587964 |  41.802045 |  -87.587743 | TBA295399226000 | 1.41975E+11            |    29.88 |
| 41.867318 | -87.625199 |  41.867463 |  -87.625158 | TBA295579366000 | 57137334115            |    16.44 |
| 41.823113 | -87.773061 |  41.823028 |  -87.772978 | TBA295889245000 | 609866840              |     11.7 |
| 41.880609 | -87.643551 |  41.880643 |  -87.643825 | TBA296616086000 | 73353853103            |       23 |
| 41.879607 | -87.787703 |   41.87942 |  -87.787827 | TBA297207405000 | 1.52921E+11            |    23.22 |
```

Sample dataset for route table

```
|  route_id   |   tracking_id   |
|-------------|-----------------|
| 5606318-230 | TBA291146931000 |
| 5615178-242 | TBA291146931000 |
| 5608371-231 | TBA291146931000 |
| 5619196-12  | TBA294192909000 |
| 5615178-249 | TBA294636573000 |
| 5615178-15  | TBA295159303000 |
| 5615178-266 | TBA295399226000 |
| 5608971-29  | TBA295399226000 |
| 5616765-168 | TBA295579366000 |
| 5615178-43  | TBA295889245000 |
| 5611715-191 | TBA296616086000 |
| 5615178-239 | TBA296616086000 |
| 5613961-24  | TBA296616086000 |
| 5615178-46  | TBA297207405000 |
| 5615178-45  | TBA297381148000 |
| 5615178-327 | TBA297914514000 |
| 5615178-122 | TBA298006586000 |
| 5615178-220 | TBA298012265000 |
| 5615178-203 | TBA298150824000 |
| 5615178-4   | TBA298172704000 |
```

Current final output(wrong as the no of packages should have been 16 for this destination address id):

```
| zero_to_ten_percentage | eleven_to_twenty_percentage | twenty_to_fifty_percentage | gt_50_percentage | destination_address_id |  route_id   | total_packages |
|------------------------|-----------------------------|----------------------------|------------------|------------------------|-------------|----------------|
|             50.6849315 |                  41.0958904 |                   4.109589 |                0 |           100529310603 | 5726011-18  |             73 |
|             50.6849315 |                  41.0958904 |                   4.109589 |                0 |           100529310603 | 5132076-67  |             73 |
|             50.6849315 |                  41.0958904 |                   4.109589 |                0 |           100529310603 | 5741216-13  |             73 |
|             50.6849315 |                  41.0958904 |                   4.109589 |                0 |           100529310603 | 5722811-179 |             73 |
|             50.6849315 |                  41.0958904 |                   4.109589 |                0 |           100529310603 | 5647148-145 |             73 |
|             50.6849315 |                  41.0958904 |                   4.109589 |                0 |           100529310603 | 5701985-94  |             73 |
|             50.6849315 |                  41.0958904 |                   4.109589 |                0 |           100529310603 | 5657147-148 |             73 |
|             50.6849315 |                  41.0958904 |                   4.109589 |                0 |           100529310603 | 5713302-122 |             73 |
|             50.6849315 |                  41.0958904 |                   4.109589 |                0 |           100529310603 | 5627191-48  |             73 |
```

Desired output:

```
| zero_to_ten_percentage | eleven_to_twenty_percentage | twenty_to_fifty_percentage | gt_50_percentage | destination_address_id |  route_id   | total_packages |
|------------------------|-----------------------------|----------------------------|------------------|------------------------|-------------|----------------|
|             50.6849315 |                  41.0958904 |                   4.109589 |                0 |           100529310603 | 5726011-18  |             16 |
|             50.6849315 |                  41.0958904 |                   4.109589 |                0 |           100529310603 | 5132076-67  |             16 |
|             50.6849315 |                  41.0958904 |                   4.109589 |                0 |           100529310603 | 5741216-13  |             16 |
|             50.6849315 |                  41.0958904 |                   4.109589 |                0 |           100529310603 | 5722811-179 |             16 |
|             50.6849315 |                  41.0958904 |                   4.109589 |                0 |           100529310603 | 5647148-145 |             16 |
|             50.6849315 |                  41.0958904 |                   4.109589 |                0 |           100529310603 | 5701985-94  |             16 |
|             50.6849315 |                  41.0958904 |                   4.109589 |                0 |           100529310603 | 5657147-148 |             16 |
|             50.6849315 |                  41.0958904 |                   4.109589 |                0 |           100529310603 | 5713302-122 |             16 |
|             50.6849315 |                  41.0958904 |                   4.109589 |                0 |           100529310603 | 5627191-48  |             16 |
```

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE T3 AS 
SELECT  DISTINCT T2_2.lat1
,T2_2.long1
,T2_2.actual_lat
,T2_2.actual_long
,T2_2.tracking_id
,T2_2.destination_address_id
,round((CASE WHEN ((lat1 IS NOT NULL AND lat1 != '') 
AND (lat1 = actual_lat) 
AND (actual_long IS NOT NULL AND actual_long != '') AND (long1 = actual_long)) THEN 0               
WHEN ((lat1 IS NOT NULL AND lat1 != '') 
AND (long1 IS NOT NULL AND long1 != '') 
AND (actual_lat IS NOT NULL AND actual_lat != '') 
AND (actual_long IS NOT NULL AND actual_long != '')) 
THEN (ACOS(ROUND(COS(ACOS(- 1) / 180 * (90 - lat1)) * COS(ACOS(- 1) / 180 * (90 - actual_lat)) 
+ SIN(ACOS(- 1) / 180 * (90 -lat1)) * SIN(ACOS(- 1) / 180 * (90 - actual_lat)) * COS(ACOS(- 1) / 180 
* (long1 - actual_long)), 20)) * 6378137
        ) ELSE NULL END
                ), 2) distance
FROM T2_2
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3 , 4, 5, 6
ORDER BY tracking_id
;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE route AS
SELECT DISTINCT route_id,
tracking_id
FROM routing_na.actuals 
WHERE tracking_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT tracking_id FROM T3)
ORDER BY tracking_id
;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE T3_final AS
SELECT DISTINCT distance
,T3.tracking_id
,destination_address_id
,route_id
FROM T3, route
WHERE T3.tracking_id = route.tracking_id
ORDER BY T3.tracking_id
;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE packages AS
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tracking_id) packs
,destination_address_id
FROM T3_final
GROUP by destination_address_id
;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE T4 AS /* Doing some percentage calculations based on the new buckets created in the previous temp table namely percentage calculations out of total  */
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN distance BETWEEN 0 AND 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)a
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN distance BETWEEN 11 AND 20  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)b
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN distance BETWEEN 21 AND 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)c
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN distance > 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)d
      ,packages.destination_address_id
      ,a/packs::DECIMAL(10,2) * 100 AS e  
      ,b/packs::DECIMAL(10,2) * 100 AS f
      ,c/packs::DECIMAL(10,2) * 100 AS g
      ,d/packs::DECIMAL(10,2) * 100 AS h
      ,packs AS Total_packages
FROM T3_final, packages
WHERE T3_final.destination_address_id = packages.destination_address_id
GROUP BY  packages.destination_address_id,packs
ORDER BY packages.destination_address_id
;

SELECT DISTINCT e zero_to_ten_percentage
,f eleven_to_twenty_percentage
,g twenty_to_fifty_percentage
,h gt_50_percentage
,T4.destination_address_id
,route_id
,Total_packages
FROM T3_final, T4
WHERE T3_final.destination_address_id = T4.destination_address_id
ORDER BY T4.destination_address_id
;
```

[Actual no of tracking ids for a particular destination_address_id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyr9z.jpg)

Comment: T3, route share both tables sample data and expected output in text format not in image

Comment: If the T3 table has 1 tracking id to many tracking ids in the route table then that would explain the duplicates. You can use the distinct clause during the insert to add unique values.

Comment: The image is not helping. In order to get better help here, you need to provide input, desired output, and the mismatched output clearly.

Comment: in editing your question you have removed the original sql!

Comment: It's extremely difficult to answer a question like this without seeing the SQL being used.

Comment: ah i see the sql. maybe you should have created separate blocks for your data and code (i didnt scroll down)

Comment: Can you provide a minimal dataset for us to try and reproduce the situation?

Comment: Any luck finding what is wrong? Do I need to give some additional info?